# RSpec unable to autoload my Grape rack app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, ruby-grape

I am trying to run some request specs using Rspec in Rails 4 but keep coming up against an error that RSpec

`'load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Api, expected /Users/sammason/Sites/coupons/app/api/api.rb to define it (LoadError)`

My folder structure is like so

```
-- app
--- api
--- api.rb
```

Inside of the `api.rb` I have this

```
class API < Grape::API
  prefix 'api'
  version 'v1', using: :path
  format :json

  mount ::V1::Base
end
```

And in `routes.rb`

```
 mount API, at: '/'
```

When I run the application the api works and I can use it however whenever I run RSpec I get the `load_missing_constant` error

Comment: Did you find any solution to it yet?

Comment: No I never found a solution to this in the end